# How do I prevent data from being maliciously returned from Postgres functions?

Tags: postgresql

I have a role that can execute a function "aggregate" that is set with security definer. The purpose of this function is to allow execution of another untrusted function, ensuring that only two integers are allowed to be returned from it. The untrusted functions are written ad-hoc by users and they are required to be pgpsql functions.

To that end, the aggregate function does the following:

1. Calls another function, by name, based on a parameter p_indicator.
2. Ensure that only two numbers were returned by the p_indicator function.
3. Returns the two numbers.

How do I ensure that the subfunction that is called has not way of sending row level data to the client through other means than RETURN.

- Privileges - I ensured that only select privileges are in place so that the subfunction cannot insert or update data into other tables to retrieve later.
- Exceptions - I wrapped the entire function in a try-catch-other and returned a generic exception instead of one that could contain data.

What I haven't been able to figure out:

- Notices/Debug - The sub-function could contain a RAISE NOTICE that will return row level data to the client. I thought that I could lock this down by setting the [client_min_messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-logging.html). However, I have run into two major issues with this: 1. the client can just set the client_min_messages in the sub-function overriding what I set. 2. the client can use RAISE INFO which magically is not affected by the setting.
- What else? - Other than RAISE and RETURN, how is a function able to "send" data to the client?

I will say that I have partially resolved this issue by putting a sign/verify process around the functions. That is, someone has to review the function, cryptographically sign it, and it is then verified against known public keys before being created in the database. However, I would still like to safeguard the aggregate function if at all possible.

I was excited to see the [leak proof and security barrier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html) keywords; however, that only seems to affect views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that there is currently no way to reliably block RAISE INFO and RAISE NOTICE.

It's also possible, though unlikely, that the attacker could write code which would trigger a backend crash, and secret information could be leaked to the client in the crash message.  If the attacker has any access to the filesystem on the server, even temp space, there are quite a few different exploits they could potentially develop.

There's also the fact that PL/pgSQL is a turing-complete language, and as such is open to very clever exploits which would create covert channels. Ultimately, only your "audited and signed" function approach is going to be successful, because you can't win in a battle where the attacker has the resources of an entire programming language available, even one as primitive as that one.